# Import txt file and a log file into Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I had just started with Jupyter notebooks and Python. During the course  had a learing task where I should:

I want to know top 10 most common hours in the data_log.log

The data looks something like this and the datestamp is in brackets [ ].

```
    64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:05:49 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/edit/Main/ouble_bounce_sender?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariable HTTP/1.1" 401 12846
        64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:19:03:58 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Message_size_limit?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariable HTTP/1.1" 401 12846
        206-15-133-154.dialup.ziplink.net - - [11/Mar/2004:16:33:23 -0800] "HEAD /twiki/bin/view/Main/SpamAssassinDeleting HTTP/1.1" 200 0
```

I started with:

```
import pandas as pd 
    dataset= pd.read_fwf('data_log.log')
```

How can I access the first two numbers after the : in the brackets?

How should I after that count them I print out top 10 in a table with hour and count as a table headings

hour count

10      5

14      3

10      2

Answer (score 0):

This is best solved using Regular Expressions. See the [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html) for the syntax to fit your data. This will allow your program to extract sections of the data from your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Simulating your text file:

```
file_data = """
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:05:49 -0800] "GET 
/twiki/bin/edit/Main/ouble_bounce_sender?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariable 
HTTP/1.1" 401 12846
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:19:03:58 -0800] "GET 
/twiki/bin/edit/Main/Message_size_limit?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariable 
HTTP/1.1" 401 12846
206-15-133-154.dialup.ziplink.net - - [11/Mar/2004:16:33:23 -0800] "HEAD 
/twiki/bin/view/Main/SpamAssassinDeleting HTTP/1.1" 200 0"""
```

Using `pandas.read_csv` to import the file:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(file_data), names=[0, 'hour', 2, 3], sep=':', engine='python')
```

This gives a messy DataFrame, but you just care about the hour column:

```
                                                   0  hour   2  \
0                      64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004    16   5   
1                      64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004    19   3   
2  206-15-133-154.dialup.ziplink.net - - [11/Mar/...    16  33   

                                                   3  
0  49 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/edit/Main/ouble_boun...  
1  58 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Message_si...  
2  23 -0800] "HEAD /twiki/bin/view/Main/SpamAssas...
```

Get the hour counts:

```
df['hour'].value_counts()
Out[141]: 
16    2
19    1
```

Comment: Thanks. However it says that my file is not defined. What kind misstake am I doing?df= pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data_log.log), names=[0, 'hour', 2, 3], sep=':', engine='python')                                                                                         
     NameError: name 'access_log' is not defined

Comment: I guess I figured it out why it wasnt defined, because I havent defined it. However when I tried defined it with  logg=pd.read_csv('data_log.log') then it said TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not DataFrame. How can I solve it?

Comment: @John I don't have your file for the input, so I used the text you supplied with the StringIO object.  You will have to replace that part of the function call with your file path.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am not really sure what I should replace. df = pd.read_csv('/Users/john/Desktop/data_log.log'), names=[0, 'hour', 2, 3], sep=':', engine='python') is NOT working. Is it because it is a csv file? If so, how can I handle the problem?